# HTML form in CSS grid layout

Tags: html, css, forms, css-grid

I am trying to make a form for a site and I use CSS grid layout for this form since its a kind of big survey form and it makes sense to use grid layout for it.
However I am encountering a issue that I need some help.
I am attaching you how it looks on Mozilla Firefox. Why Basic Info and Accommodation aren't aligned since both are on the same grid system and justify content is set on center?

[image: layout]

Below is my CSS and HTML code.

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  ;
}

.container {
  display: grid;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
  grid-template-rows: 1fr 1.5fr 1fr;
  grid-template-areas: "progress progress progress" "basicinfo basicinfo basicinfo" "page2 page2 page2";
}

.container .progressbar {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 5rem 5rem 5rem 5rem;
  margin: 5px;
  padding: 5px;
  ;
  grid-area: progress;
  justify-content: center;
  align-content: center;
}

.container .page1 {
  display: grid;
  grid-area: basicinfo;
  justify-content: center;
}

.container .page2 {
  padding-top: 10px;
  display: grid;
  grid-area: page2;
  justify-content: center;
}

.container .field {
  padding-top: 1rem;
}

.container .page2 .page2dropdown {
  display: flex;
  width: 60%;
}

.container .page .facilities {
  display: flex;
}

.container .page2 .page2dropdown #hotelpeople {
  margin-top: 10px;
  ;
}

.container .page1 input {
  border: none;
  border-bottom: 3px solid cyan;
  margin-top: 5px;
  bottom: -5px;
  outline: none;
  position: relative;
  border-spacing: 5px;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-size: 1rem;
  line-height: 2em;
}

.container .title span {
  text-decoration: none;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  display: block;
  position: relative;
}

.container .title span::after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  width: 7em;
  background: #2699FB;
  height: .6em;
  bottom: -3px;
  top: 17px;
  left: -2px;
}
```

```html
<form action="" method="post" class="myform">

  <div class="container">

    <div class="progressbar">

      <div class="step">
        <p>Name</p>
        <div class="bullet"><span>1</span></div>
        <div class="check"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="step">
        <p>Name</p>
        <div class="bullet"><span>1</span></div>
        <div class="check"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="step">
        <p>Name</p>
        <div class="bullet"><span>1</span></div>
        <div class="check"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="step">
        <p>Name</p>
        <div class="bullet"><span>1</span></div>
        <div class="check"></div>
      </div>


    </div>

    <div class="page1">

      <div class="title"> <span>Basic Info:</span></div>

      <div class="field">
        <input type="text" placeholder="your name">
      </div>

      <div class="field">

        <input type="text" placeholder="your email">
      </div>

      <div class="field">

        <input type="text" placeholder="repeat your email">
      </div>


      <div class="field">
        <label for="dates">Dates</label><br>
        <input type="date" id="checkin" name="checkin">
        <input type="date" id="checkout" name="checkout">

      </div>

      <div class="field">
        <div class="slidecontainer">
          <input type="range" min="1" max="100" value="50" class="slider" id="myRange">
        </div>

      </div>


      <div class="field">
        <input type="text" placeholder="Write us your comments">

      </div>

      <div class="field btns">
        <button>Next</button>
      </div>

    </div>


    <div class="page2">

      <div class="title"> <span>Acommodation:</span> <input type="checkbox" id="acommodation" name="acommodation" value="acommodation"><label for="acommodation"> I dont want acommodation</label></div>

      <div class="page2dropdown">
        <div class="field" id="hotel">
          <label for="people">How many people:</label>

          <select name="people" id="hotelpeople">
            <option value="1">1</option>
            <option value="2">2</option>
            <option value="3">3</option>
            <option value="4">Audi</option>
          </select>

        </div>

        <div class="field">
          <label for="people" id="bedrooms">How many people:</label>

          <select name="people" id="hotelpeople">
            <option value="1">1</option>
            <option value="2">2</option>
            <option value="3">3</option>
            <option value="4">Audi</option>
          </select>

        </div>

      </div>


      <div class="facilities">
        <div class="field">
          Facilities that you want included to your acommodation place<br>


          <label class="facilitiescheckbox">One
            <input type="checkbox" checked="checked">
            <span class="checkmark"></span>
          </label>
          <label class="facilitiescheckbox">Two
            <input type="checkbox">
            <span class="checkmark"></span>
          </label>
          <label class="facilitiescheckbox">Three
            <input type="checkbox">
            <span class="checkmark"></span>
          </label>
          <label class="facilitiescheckbox">Four
            <input type="checkbox">
            <span class="checkmark"></span>
          </label>
          <label class="facilitiescheckbox">One
            <input type="checkbox" checked="checked">
            <span class="checkmark"></span>
          </label>
          <label class="facilitiescheckbox">Two
            <input type="checkbox">
            <span class="checkmark"></span>
          </label>
          <label class="facilitiescheckbox">Three
            <input type="checkbox">
            <span class="checkmark"></span>
          </label>
          <label class="facilitiescheckbox">Four
            <input type="checkbox">
            <span class="checkmark"></span>
          </label>

        </div>
      </div>


    </div>

    <div class="field btns">
      <button>Next</button>
    </div>

  </div>


  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Could you send the HTML too please?

Comment: thank you! i have edited and i have my html as as well even if its a bit long!

Comment: any luck?! still i am trying to figure out why this is happening and cant find a logic explanation. I even consider to turn the whole questionnaire in a more traditional inline-blocl and block displays but i thought CSS grid layout is more logical